# Fetching the Data from Amazon Dynamo DB

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have created One Primary Key and One Sorted Key in my Table "Question_Table" with a DBIndexHashKey and with a DBRangeKey. Now I want to retrieve the data from that table in my Android Application Code.

I am aware of the Query:

Question_Table qq = mapper.load(Question_Table.class,1,2);

where 1 is one of the primary keys and 2 is the Range Key. I tried to perform the following operations, just to check whether it's working or not.

String s = qq.getQuestion_Body();
System.out.println(s);

(Question_Body is one of the Column in the Question_Table)

But it showed me an error.

Is there any other method to fetch the data from the Dynamo DB having two Primary keys, with the help of one primary key and one Range key.

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
               Caused by: com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMappingException: Couldn't invoke public void com.atulpatidar.farmcartsurvey.Question_Table.setQ_UUID(java.lang.String)
                  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.ReflectionUtils.safeInvoke(ReflectionUtils.java:46)
                  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.createKeyObject(DynamoDBMapper.java:493)
                  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:465)
                  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:350)
                  at com.atulpatidar.farmcartsurvey.CreateSurveyActivity$UpdateTask.doInBackground(CreateSurveyActivity.java:146)
                  at com.atulpatidar.farmcartsurvey.CreateSurveyActivity$UpdateTask.doInBackground(CreateSurveyActivity.java:111)
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "Dynamo DB having two Primary keys, with the help of one primary key and one Range key."

Comment: @Karthik It means I have one partition key and a sorted key to uniquely identify a record in my table. I was looking for a method by which I can retrieve the data(record) in my application with the help of these two keys.

Comment: you should be able to use query api with the hash key and a range key